# How to update a database with SQL call using parameters (Foreign Key)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

There is a problem with updating a foreign key's ID. So when this SQL call is initiated the foreign key LocationID does not update but the Question attribute is updated. Is there any reason why this would be the case?

```
// Set strSQL to empty string.
String strSQL = "";

// Develop SQL call.
strSQL = "UPDATE Question ";
strSQL +=   "SET LocationID = @LocationID, Question = @Question ";
strSQL += "WHERE LocationID = @OldLocationID";

// Define the network connection to the SQL Server database.
SqlConnection objSqlConnection = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["2020LJCDT"].ConnectionString);

// Set up the SQL command object
SqlCommand objSqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
objSqlCommand.Connection = objSqlConnection;
objSqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
objSqlCommand.CommandText = strSQL;

// Define the input parameters
objSqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LocationID", ddlLocation.SelectedValue);
objSqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Question", txtQuestion.Text);
objSqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OldLocationID", lblLocationID.Text);

// Open the connection
objSqlConnection.Open();

// Get number of rows affected. 
numberOfRecords = objSqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

//Close the data reader and the connection.
objSqlConnection.Close();
```

Comment: Make sure @LocationID has proper value and check if same query runs properly direclty against db.

Comment: @user2316116 It has a proper value and runs perfectly if I hard code it in SSMS.

Comment: it can't be true, try to debug/response.write ddlLocation.SelectedValue or hardcode strSQL with test value to see that sql will update database as expected. I still think that ddlLocation.SelectedValue has previous value, so when sql is executed it updates LocationID with its previous value, so you can't see any difference. P.S. hint: when writing `strSQL = @"..."` no need to do multiple `strSQL += ...`

Comment: @user2316116 Here is the screenshot: http://prntscr.com/s70pb7                                     That happens to be not the case. The values look like there being passed correctly. If I hard code the values in the code behind it does not work also. If I hard code it in SSMS it works thou.

Comment: Well, I can only guess that you overwrite the value somewhere after that. If same query works in SSMS, then scheme/query should be correct and same should work from the application. On your screenshot, when staying on close() do you see a change in SSMS?

Comment: @user2316116 No I do not.

Comment: @user2316116 Yes, you were correct. It is being overwritten. I have an Update Command on my aspx page.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was found. After walking each `line of code` while checking the database I found that the database was being overwritten by the `Update Command`. The SQL call was indeed changing the database to the correct `LocationID` but then the `Update Command` was changing it right back when its method was called in the code-behind. To solve this problem the `Update Command` needed to go. Unfortunately, I had to leave the `Update Command` be to keep the error messages that were in place. To fix this I just made the `Update Command` a blank string. It was a silly mistake that could have been avoided but I am still learning ASP.Net as I am still a beginner. It's still probably not a good idea to have a blank `Update Command` in the code but I haven't found out if this will cause any problems down the road.

```
  <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="sdsListViewQuestion"
    ConnectionString="<%$ConnectionStrings:2020LJCDT %>"
    OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}"
    InsertCommand="INSERT
                     INTO Question
                        (
                          LocationID,
                          Question
                        )
                   VALUES
                        (
                          @LocationID,
                          @Question
                        ) ;"
    UpdateCommand=";"
    DeleteCommand="DELETE
                     FROM Question
                    WHERE QuestionID = @original_QuestionID;">

</asp:SqlDataSource>
```